# Can app store update notifications be disables on iOS?

Tags: ios, notifications

I don't want a popup telling me when my apps can be updated.  Any ready to get rid of these without jailbreaking?

I wouldn't mind getting rid of the badge, too.  But I find it less annoying than the popup.

Comment: I never get popups! I didn't even know you could get popups! Did you check the Notification Center settings?

Comment: Do you ALWAYS get this popups or only on certain apps? I do have only ONE app that throws a popup/push notification when there's a update available. This is an app setting and not related to the app store prefs.

Comment: no clue where it came from.  It just said that 3 app store updates were available.  I never enable push notifications in any of my apps.